# What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?

Tags: support, error-message, 404-not-found

I have journeyed thus and bruised into the lands of [the error page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/404). There, upon the hill I see a vision as such:

[image: Stack Overflow 404]

For those reading with images off:

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

How can I compile it?

More to the point, what is the joke?

Comment: A little context might be helpful.  Where did you see this on SO?

Comment: Have a look at [this collection of 404 pages](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/08/17/404-error-pages-reloaded/).

Comment: What's this font?

Comment: [Liberation Mono](http://www.dafont.com/liberation-mono.font) looks similar.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. I submitted it to WTF: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/295724/?flush=1

Comment: Just to follow up, the font is Pragmata: http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fsd/pragmata/tt/

Comment: I think there's a bug in the Befunge version:

`#        - skip next cell (it's a space anyway)
define    - pushed to stack (space is ignored)
v         - turn down
e44       - pushed to stack
.         - pop value and print as integer, output so far is "4"
definee4  - current stack
*         - pop 4, pop e, mult and push
define404 - current stack (404 is one value)
>         - turn right
.         - pop and print as integer, "4404" is current output
@         - end`

Comment: @Alowishus, you (and some earlier editors) have missed the "newline symbol" in the image; meanwhile Beetle has fixed the text version.

Comment: It looks C code.

Comment: I compiled it on a Linux. The compiler gave many warnings, but the result is very simple: it prints the string "404" to the stdout. **The post is clearly on-topic.**

Comment: RIP the error page :(

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Want a step-by-step through it?  I'm the [original author of the polyglot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27846).

The easy versions are Python, Perl, and Ruby: the only code executed is

```
print(202*2);exit();
```

because they all treat `#` as a line-comment.  Obviously, the code prints "404" and exits the program.

---

The C code is fairly easy to read, but even easier if you run it through a preprocessor:

```
main(){putchar(4+putchar(putchar(52)-4));return 0;};exit();
```

Your standard `main` function is declared there, and `exit` is also declared as a function with an implicit return type of `int` (`exit` is effectively ignored).

`putchar` was used because you don't need any `#include` to use it; you give it an integer argument and it puts the corresponding ASCII character to stdout and returns the same value you gave it.  So, we put 52 (which is `4`); then we subtract 4 and output `0`; then we add 4 to output `4` again.

---

The brainf*ck code will be a little more difficult to understand, but essentially it's the same as the C code.

```
+->       Effectively ignored from earlier part of code
++++++++  Put 8 in first memory location
[>++++++<-] Add 6 to second location; decrement first location; 
            repeat until first is 0; effectively this does 6*8 into 2nd location
>++++.    Move back into 2nd location and add 4 so we have a char of 52; print it
----.     Decrement 4 times to output a 0
++++.     Increment 4 times and output a 4
>.        Move pointer and output a null
```

Actually, that last line wasn't supposed to work that way.  The last part was supposed to be `++++<` before the `>.`  Oh well, it's up there now.

---

Befunge is my favorite of the group.  I recommend [The Visual Befunge Applet](http://www.ashleymills.com/?q=befunge_applet_lite) if you want to see it in action.

Essentially, all the characters in `define` are pushed on the stack and never used.  Then `v` points our instruction vector downwards.  Then we push another `e` on the stack, which happens to be an ASCII value of 101.  Push 4 on the stack, multiply, turn right, hit the `.` and print 404 to the screen.  `@` stops the program there.

Comment: Is there a room for whitespace version? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Comment: Yes, there should be room, but since the 404 is an image, it would be somewhat difficult to convey whitespace :)

Comment: Btw, it is executable PHP as well (http://codepad.org/Med97xh4) (With the exception of the opening PHP tag.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [Yes, there is an `exit` pseudo-builtin.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit)

Comment: @nneonneo: Gah, of course there is.

Comment: WRONG: See _ISO/IEC 9899-1999 §7.19.7.9-1_. `putchar` is supposed to be defined in `<stdio.h>`, not implicitly.

Comment: @Cole Johnson - OBJECTION, IRRELEVANT (or pedantic, or missing the point, take your pick): He said "you don't need any #include to use it", *he did not say it's a built-in*.  Whether or not it's implicit doesn't matter.  It emits a warning, but the implicit declaration works (tested in llvm, gcc & visual studio).

Comment: Ok, now I have an objection (befunge one)...
the problem is, in the standard befunge93 instructions, writing just 'e' doesn't mean anything. It's simply ignored. And by befunge98 standard, it means 15 not 101. if you wanted to actually put character 101 in the buffer, you had to escape it.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Well, apparently the author was aiming at something around C89/90 where calling undeclared functions was still legal. Albeit plain `main()` is illegal in C89/90 as well. So, formally this is not standard C but sort of "street C"/"pidgin C".

Comment: The Befunge code is not to spec, and the only implementation that it appears to work in (the one you've linked) appears to have been deleted.

Answer (score 106):

Here's my shot at a 404. It's not a polyglot, but it's more visually interesting:

```
#define _ f++>o--*ur-- || o--*h++ || f++*o--*ur;
int f = 0, o = 0, ur = 0, h = 0;
main(){f++;o--*ur;o--*h;f*our();printf("%d\n", (f-o-ur));}/*oh, f*/our(){
_-_     _-_      _-_      _-_     _-_
_-_     _-_     -_-_-     _-_     _-_
_-_     _-_  _-_-   -_-_  _-_     _-_
_-_-_-_-_-_  _-_-   -_-_  _-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_  _-_-   -_-_  _-_-_-_-_-_
        _-_  _-_-   -_-_          _-_
        _-_  _-_-   -_-_          _-_
        _-_  _-_-   -_-_          _-_
        _-_     -_-_-             _-_
        _-_      _-_              _-_
}
```

Comment: Seems like the second line can be replaced wth `int f,o,ur = 0,h = f+o+ur;`. Is it legal to omit the `int` as well?

Comment: @immibis: Simply omitting `int` is illegal in any standard C. At least some decl-specifier is required, meaning that you can replace `int` with `static` or `const`, but you can't just leave it blank. Plain `main()` is illegal in standard C for the same reason. It can be `extern main()`, but not just `main()`.

Answer (score 56):

It's from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/27846#27846).  It's a [Polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot%5F%28computing%29).

Comment: It is actually from the official 404 page on SO now.

Answer (score 38):

The joke is that it is a program that prints '404' to the screen.

The program is a polyglot.  It is valid in C, Python, Perl, Ruby, Befunge-93, and Brainf*ck.

Answer (score 30):

It's a polyglot for **C** (not **C++**), **brainf*****, **Python**, **Perl**, **Ruby**, and (nearly) any other scripting language for that matter. Interestingly, it is also a **Befunge-93** program. Here's a comprehensive breakdown.

---

## C

After preprocessing, the program becomes:

```
main(){putchar(4+putchar(putchar(52)-4));return 0;}
```

The function `putchar` is stated by the standard as `int putchar(int c)` inside `<stdio.h>`. As there is no `#include` directive, this is not a valid **C** program either. It could be valid if there is a compiler that implicitly includes `<stdio.h>` if it notices certain functions being used, but I have yet to encounter one. It could also be valid if you were using [gcc and added `-include "{stdio}"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-from-command-line-gcc) to the command line. However, the `-include` parameter expects a *relative* path.

If there was an `#include <stdio.h>` line, the program would still be valid in scripting languages (as explained below), and `brainf***` as the only control characters are `<>`. It would not function however as the pointer is set to `0` on start, and setting it to `-1` *should* crash the interpreter.

Disregarding all of that, when we reformat the code a bit, and replace `52` with its ASCII equivalent (`'4'`), we get:

```
int main() {
    putchar(4 + putchar(putchar('4') - 4));
    return 0;
}
```

As for the `putchar` declaration, it is defined by the standard to return it's input, like `realloc`. First, this program prints a `4`, then takes the ASCII value (`52`), subtracts 4 (`48`), prints that (ASCII `0`), adds 4 (`52`), prints that (`4`), then finally terminates. This results in the following output:

```
404
```

As for this polyglot being valid **C++**, unfortunately, it is not as **C++** requires an explicit return type for functions. This program takes advantage of the fact that **C** requires functions without an explicit return type to be `int`.

---

## brainf***

`brainf***` works by reading its input character by character, and ignoring anything except the `brainf***` operators (any of `.<>[]+-`). This results in the following (line breaks included, sans first line):

```
+-
>++++++++[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.

>.
```

Stepping through this program, we get:

```
+- ; nothing
>  ; set ptr to 1
++++++++ ; set arr[1] to 8 (iter count)
[
  > ; set ptr to 2
  ++++++ ; add 6 to arr[2]
  < ; set ptr to 1
  - ; decrement loop count
] ; arr[2] now contains 48 (6*8)
> ; set ptr to 2
++++. ; set arr[2] to 52 ('4') and print
----. ; set arr[2] to 48 ('0') and print
++++. ; set arr[2] to 52 and print
>. ; print arr[3] (`\0`)
```

The reasoning behind the output of a null character at the end is unknown to me. However, this all results in the same output as above:

```
404
```

---

## Scripting languages

Nearly all popular scripting languages (**Perl**, **Python**, **Ruby**, etc.) contain a function called `print` that casts whatever is passed to it to a string then writes it to `stdout`. They also interpret `#` as a single line comment (akin **C** and **C++**'s `//`).

This results in the following with the "comments" removed:

```
print(202*2);
exit();
```

It should be obvious what this does.

---

## Befunge-93

*TODO*

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

Comment: might as well finish up that TODO

Comment: "This program takes advantage of the fact that C requires functions without an explicit return type to be int." Modern C no longer supports the "implicit `int` rule". And even the original C89/90, which supported "implicit `int`" (and implicit function declarations), did not allow empty *decl-specifier-seq* in declarations. So, plain `main()` is illegal in any standard C.

Comment: You'll never finish that TODO, because the code does not actually work in Befunge-93.

Answer (score 19):

For copying purposes:

**404.poly**

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

And to see the output under the different interpreters:

**404.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'ruby:      ' $(ruby 404.poly)
echo 'python:    ' $(python 404.poly)
echo 'perl:      ' $(perl 404.poly)
echo 'brainfuck: ' $(bf 404.poly)
echo 'c:         ' $(gcc -xc -o404 404.poly 2>/dev/null && ./404)

#     befunge:     http://www.ashleymills.com/?q=befunge%5Fapplet%5Flite
```

Answer (score 15):

I added in a [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) 404 output.

```
# define v putchar               

#define print(x)    main(){ v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0; }/*   
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/    
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@/exit()
```

The tabs don't come accross very well:

```
#_define_v_putchar[tab][tab]__[tab]_[tab]_
_
#define_print(x)[tab]main(){_v(4+v(v(52)-4));return_0;_}/*[tab]
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/_[tab]
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@/exit()
<blank line>
```

The first line puts the value 202 on the stack

- (SS)  Command to put a number on that stack
- (STTSSTSTS) 202 in binary (S=0, T=1)
- (L)   Ends the number

The next 404 is produced

- (SLS) Duplicate the top of the stack (adds a second 202)
- (TS)  Arithmetic operation
- (SS)  Adds the top two numbers on the stack (202 + 202 = 404)

Finally 404 is printed

- (TL)  IO command
- (ST)  Indicates the top of the stack should be printed as an integer

The last two just end the program

- (LL)  End of program

Comment: [Here](http://wonderfl.net/c/gpUu/fullscreen) is an online interpreter for whitespace.

Comment: Maybe the newlines/some copy/paste artifact is affecting it, but that gives a syntax error for me

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the space in the "return 0;" and somehow dropped it out when testing. The new version should work.

Answer (score -10):

This code using **Python, C** test OK!

```python
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4)); return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

### Py3 404

https://repl.it/FK9L/0

### C 404

https://repl.it/FK8v/0
https://repl.it/FK8v/1

[image]
[image]