# "Page not found" is a bit of a mess

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, error-message

I came across a [Page Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/) and realised how much of a mess it is:

#### Annotated image for people who like images

[image]

#### Words for search engines who don't

- First off "Page Not Found" implies that this was an accident, perhaps rename to "Page Removed"
- There is `padding: 3px` on `.revision-comment` `span` which makes for some very odd looking text
- The joke text referring to the [polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code) doesn't match up to it in the page in any way, which detracts from the useful information - maybe move this text to the right column next to the image
- The font size for the suggested questions is HUGE and there's no delimiting which makes them run into each other
- "Google search" needs a bullet point

#### Snippet for >10k users

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>
    
    <title>Page Not Found - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91" />
            
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=fb0ca4ff15b3">
    
<style type="text/css">
    .content-page > ul > li, .search-results { margin-bottom:20px; } 
    .search-results { padding-top: 10px; font-size: 80%; }
    .question-hyperlink { font-weight: normal; }
    .leftcol { width:420px; float:left }
    .rightcol { width:510px; float:right; margin-bottom:30px; }
</style>

    
    
    
</head>
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
    <noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <div id="overlay-header"></div>
    <div id="custom-header"></div>




<div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-wrapper">

        <div class="js-topbar-dialog-corral">

<div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno">
    <div class="header">
        <h3><a href="//stackoverflow.com">current community</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content current-site-container">
        <ul class="current-site">
                <li>
                        <div class="related-links">
            <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })"
>chat</a>
                    <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:7 })"
>blog</a>
                    <a href="/users/logout" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:8 })"
>log out</a>
    </div>




    <a href="//stackoverflow.com"
       class="current-site-link site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="1"
       data-gps-track="
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:3 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div>
        Stack Overflow
    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="related-site">
                        <div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
        <span class="L-shaped-icon"></span>
    </div>

                    



    <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="552"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:552, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:4 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
        Meta Stack Overflow
    </a>

                </li>
                            <li class="related-site">
                        <div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
        <span class="L-shaped-icon"></span>
    </div>

                    <a class="site-link js-gps-track"
                       href="//careers.stackoverflow.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=site-ui&utm_campaign=multicollider"
                            data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:9 })"
>
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-careers" title="Stack Overflow Careers"></div>
                        Stack Overflow Careers
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="header" id="your-communities-header">
        <h3>
                <a href="//stackexchange.com/users/1217794/?tab=accounts">your communities</a>
        </h3>
            
            <a href="#" id="edit-pinned-sites">edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="cancel-pinned-sites" style="display: none;">cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content" id="your-communities-section">
            
            <ul class="my-sites">
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//stackoverflow.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="1"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:1, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div>
        Stack Overflow
            <span class="rep-score">8,624</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//meta.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="4"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:4, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackexchangemeta" title="Meta Stack Exchange"></div>
        Meta Stack Exchange
            <span class="rep-score">562</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//english.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="97"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:97, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-english" title="English Language &amp; Usage"></div>
        English Language &amp; Usage
            <span class="rep-score">307</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//travel.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="273"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:273, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-travel" title="Travel"></div>
        Travel
            <span class="rep-score">241</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//ux.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="102"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:102, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-ux" title="User Experience"></div>
        User Experience
            <span class="rep-score">200</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
            </ul>
                <div class="pinned-site-editor-container" style="display: none;">
                    <input id="js-site-search-txt"
                           type="text"
                           class="site-filter-input"
                           value=""
                           placeholder="Add a Stack Exchange community"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="pin-site-btn" value="Add" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <ul class="js-found-sites found-sites"></ul>
                    <ul class="pinned-site-list sortable" data-custom-list="False">
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save-pinned-sites-btn" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <a href="#" id="reset-pinned-sites">reset to default list</a>
                </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="header">
        <h3><a href="//stackexchange.com/sites">more stack exchange communities</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="child-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="network-items">

            <a href="//stackexchange.com"
               class="topbar-icon icon-site-switcher yes-hover js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track"
               data-gps-track="site_switcher.show"
               title="A list of all 134 Stack Exchange sites">
                <span class="hidden-text">Stack Exchange</span>
            </a>

                <a href="#"
                   class="topbar-icon icon-inbox yes-hover js-inbox-button"
                   title="Recent inbox messages">
                    <span class="hidden-text">Inbox</span>
                    <span class="unread-count" style="display:none"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#"
                   class="topbar-icon icon-achievements yes-hover js-achievements-button "
                   data-unread-class=""
                   title="Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned">
                    <span class="hidden-text">Reputation and Badges</span>
                    <span class="unread-count" style="display:none">
                        
                    </span>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="topbar-links">

                <a href="/users/1185053/dav-i" class="profile-me js-gps-track" data-gps-track="profile_summary.click()">
                    <div class="gravatar-wrapper-24" title="dav_i"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74cfbdab78e99ed4856c577d41b4d351?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me"></div>
                    <div class="links-container topbar-flair">

                        <span class="reputation" title="your reputation: 8,624">
                            8,624
                        </span>
<span title="2 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">2</span></span><span title="28 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">28</span></span><span title="64 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">64</span></span>                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="links-container">
                    <span class="topbar-menu-links">



                            <a href="/review" title="Review queues - help improve the site">
                                review
                            </a>

    <a href="#" class="icon-help js-help-button" title="Help Center and other resources">
        help
        <span class="triangle"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="topbar-dialog help-dialog js-help-dialog dno">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <ul>
                                    <li>
                        <a href="/tour" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:1 })">
                            Tour
                            <span class="item-summary">
                                Start here for a quick overview of the site
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/help" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:4 })">
                        Help Center
                        <span class="item-summary">
                            Detailed answers to any questions you might have
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="//meta.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:2 })">
                            Meta
                            <span class="item-summary">
                                Discuss the workings and policies of this site
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

                    </span>
                </div>

            <div class="search-container">
                <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="search" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" />
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        StackExchange.ready(function() { StackExchange.topbar.init(); });
    </script>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <br class="cbt">
            <div id="hlogo">
                <a href="/">
                    Stack Overflow
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="hmenus">
                <div class="nav mainnavs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="youarehere"><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/help/badges">Badges</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav askquestion">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="nav-askquestion"  href="/questions/ask">Ask Question</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        



        <div id="content" class="snippet-hidden">
            


<div id="mainbar-full">
    <div class="subheader">
        <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-page leftcol">        
            <p>This question was <span class='revision-comment'>removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation</span>. Please refer to the help center for <b><a href="/help/deleted-questions">possible explanations why a question might be removed</a></b>.</p>            
        <p>We couldn&#39;t find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
Try <a href="/search?q=how is assignment made in this expression">searching for similar questions</a>                        <br>
                <div class="search-results">
<a href="/questions/7826240/how-do-nested-replacement-operators-work" class="question-hyperlink">How do nested replacement operators work?</a><br>
<a href="/questions/9214836/how-to-evaluate-expressions-in-this-tree" class="question-hyperlink">How to evaluate expressions in this tree?</a><br>
<a href="/questions/17656619/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-an-assignment-operator-using-aggregate-in-a" class="question-hyperlink">&ldquo;An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator&rdquo; using Aggregate in a Select clause</a><br>
<a href="/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation" class="question-hyperlink">Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation</a><br>
<a href="/questions/16944668/antlr4-language-with-undistinguishable-tokens" class="question-hyperlink">ANTLR4 - Language with undistinguishable tokens</a><br>
                </div>
            Google search<br>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions how+is+assignment+made+in+this+expression">how is assignment made in this expression</a>
            </li>
            <li>Browse <a href="/questions">recent questions</a></li>
            <li>Browse <a href="/tags">popular tags</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>If you feel something is missing that should be here, <a href="/contact">contact us</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">    
            <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png" width="500" alt="page not found">
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="categories">
        <div class="footerwrap">
            <div id="footer-menu">
                <div class="top-footer-links">
                        <a href="/tour">tour</a>
                    <a href="/help">help</a>
                    <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com?blb=1">blog</a>
                        <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com">chat</a>
                    <a href="http://data.stackexchange.com">data</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal">legal</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy">privacy policy</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/work-here">work here</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/mediakit">advertising info</a>

                    <a onclick='StackExchange.switchMobile("on")'>mobile</a>
                    <b><a href="/contact">contact us</a></b>
                        <b><a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">feedback</a></b>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="footer-sites">
                    <table>
    <tr>
            <th colspan=3>
                Technology
            </th>
            <th >
                Life / Arts
            </th>
            <th >
                Culture / Recreation
            </th>
            <th >
                Science
            </th>
            <th >
                Other
            </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//stackoverflow.com" title="professional and enthusiast programmers">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//serverfault.com" title="system and network administrators">Server Fault</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//superuser.com" title="computer enthusiasts and power users">Super User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//webapps.stackexchange.com" title="power users of web applications">Web Applications</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//askubuntu.com" title="Ubuntu users and developers">Ask Ubuntu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//webmasters.stackexchange.com" title="pro webmasters">Webmasters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gamedev.stackexchange.com" title="professional and independent game developers">Game Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//tex.stackexchange.com" title="users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems">TeX - LaTeX</a></li>
                            </ol></td><td><ol>
                        <li><a href="//programmers.stackexchange.com" title="professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development">Programmers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//unix.stackexchange.com" title="users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.">Unix &amp; Linux</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//apple.stackexchange.com" title="power users of Apple hardware and software">Ask Different (Apple)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//wordpress.stackexchange.com" title="WordPress developers and administrators">WordPress Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gis.stackexchange.com" title="cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals">Geographic Information Systems</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//electronics.stackexchange.com" title="electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts">Electrical Engineering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//android.stackexchange.com" title="enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system">Android Enthusiasts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//security.stackexchange.com" title="Information security professionals">Information Security</a></li>
                            </ol></td><td><ol>
                        <li><a href="//dba.stackexchange.com" title="database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community">Database Administrators</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//drupal.stackexchange.com" title="Drupal developers and administrators">Drupal Answers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//sharepoint.stackexchange.com" title="SharePoint enthusiasts">SharePoint</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//ux.stackexchange.com" title="user experience researchers and experts">User Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//mathematica.stackexchange.com" title="users of Mathematica">Mathematica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//salesforce.stackexchange.com" title="Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between">Salesforce</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology" class="more">
                                more (14)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//photo.stackexchange.com" title="professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers">Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//scifi.stackexchange.com" title="science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts">Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com" title="Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts">Graphic Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//cooking.stackexchange.com" title="professional and amateur chefs">Seasoned Advice (cooking)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//diy.stackexchange.com" title="contractors and serious DIYers">Home Improvement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//money.stackexchange.com" title="people who want to be financially literate">Personal Finance &amp; Money</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//academia.stackexchange.com" title="academics and those enrolled in higher education">Academia</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts" class="more">
                                more (10)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//english.stackexchange.com" title="linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts">English Language &amp; Usage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//skeptics.stackexchange.com" title="scientific skepticism">Skeptics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//judaism.stackexchange.com" title="those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more">Mi Yodeya (Judaism)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//travel.stackexchange.com" title="road warriors and seasoned travelers">Travel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//christianity.stackexchange.com" title="committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more">Christianity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gaming.stackexchange.com" title="passionate videogamers on all platforms">Arqade (gaming)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//bicycles.stackexchange.com" title="people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles">Bicycles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//rpg.stackexchange.com" title="gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games">Role-playing Games</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation" class="more">
                                more (21)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//math.stackexchange.com" title="people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields">Mathematics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//stats.stackexchange.com" title="people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization">Cross Validated (stats)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//cstheory.stackexchange.com" title="theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields">Theoretical Computer Science</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//physics.stackexchange.com" title="active researchers, academics and students of physics">Physics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//mathoverflow.net" title="professional mathematicians">MathOverflow</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#science" class="more">
                                more (7)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//stackapps.com" title="apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API">Stack Apps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//meta.stackexchange.com" title="meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&amp;A websites">Meta Stack Exchange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//area51.stackexchange.com" title="proposing new sites in the Stack Exchange network">Area 51</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//careers.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow Careers</a></li>
                    
                </ol>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="copyright">
                site design / logo &#169; 2015 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license">cc by-sa 3.0</a>                   with <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/" rel="license">attribution required</a>
            </div>
            <div id="svnrev">
                rev 2015.1.30.2258
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <noscript>
        <div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
    </noscript>

    <script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Plead to the powers-that-be

A bit of love for this page please?

Comment: Similar, but I believe distinct, question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256134/improve-the-404-not-found-error-page-for-deleted-questions

Comment: The page exists, you just can't see it, also i'm asking myself ever time i see it what this picture of Pseudo code means?!

Comment: @Rizier123: It's a pastiche of multiple programming languages.  The third line is written in Brainfuck.  It means humor, in other words.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But does the 'program' picture makes any sense? Like what would it do? Or is it just random code? (And if yes how wrote this?!)

Comment: @Rizier123 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Comment: For those who already got 10k rep here is the 404 for a invalid id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/-1/

Comment: @ratchetfreak I guess one fix for this would for me to get more rep :P

Comment: Since that's a page that's very specific to < 10K users, would it be too much to ask for you to create a Stack Snippet for it?  Just copy everything from the `<html>` tag down and we'd be able to see what it is you're seeing as well (potentially).

Comment: @Makoto Done! Had to cut some tags out as I hit the post size limit!

Comment: This is a [design] [bug], isn't it?

Comment: @Braiam I was hesitant to tag as a bug, but if the community feels it's appropriate then won't complain with it being added

Comment: It's definitely a bug.  It's related to the new design and shows inconsistencies, so it's a bug.  Tag it with `[design] [bug]` to get it to show up on Jin's radar.

Comment: I disagree with `First off "Page Not Found" implies that this was an accident, perhaps rename to "Page Removed"`.

Comment: @Sumurai8 How about "Page is only visible to high reputation contributors"?

Comment: @AdrianHHH because for actual 404s, where the URL is garbage and the page doesn't actually exist, it wouldn't make sense. I don't know if it's a good idea to treat these pages as 401s instead, is it necessary, does it matter? I suspect not. For a user <10k rep, that post doesn't exist, that's all that matters.

Comment: Snippet for >10k users? Finally, something I can do that 10k users can't :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot sorry for off topic comment but what is the meaning of >10k users, I also want to feel proud.

Comment: @symbolicConstant >10k = greater than 10,000 reputation. I can see your avatar swelling with pride already ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot But I don't have 10k rep, yet I can see the code snippet.

Comment: @symbolicConstant Exactly. 10k users don't normally see the "Page Not Found" page since they can see deleted questions.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Oh! thanks, now I got that!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Well, actually 10kers can see the [404 page](http://stackoverflow.com/404), just that some of the problems pointed out here won't be seen.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The HTTP spec specifically says that you can use 404 for pages that are not accessible if you want to hide the fact that the page exists. So I assume that the developers decided they didn't want to reveal that info. Whether that makes much sense for StackOverflow (especially given meta links) is a bit of another question.

Comment: Unless I've erroneously been granted 10K privileges, the linked question has been undeleted. I can see it just fine, instead of getting the 404 page.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was responding to Sumurai8's suggestion for a clearer message about the non-displaying of the page by giving another possible message. I had not studied the numeric codes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have heard the cries and have responded. We would love your feedback.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me a ping when it's live?

Comment: It's live now @dav_i

Comment: Cool, I'll try find a deleted question when I'm next at a PC

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Looks good now: http://puu.sh/fAuYn/caa5bbf3ca.png

Comment: Isn't "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation" usually highlighted? Also, maybe a *little* bit more whitespace.

Comment: It's now a bit, um, _IE_...

Comment: It feels a bit odd to me that the "Google", "similar questions", "recent questions" and "popular tags" lines don't have periods at the end, but then the "Contact us" bit does.

Answer (score 5):

A few ideas how the page could be cleaned up:

- The padding on the `revision-comment` span seems completely out of place - probably due to reusing the existing CSS class for edit comments and other post events on the post revision page. The CSS class could just be dropped entirely. If it was used for emphasis of the removal reason (which indicates if the post was deleted by OP or the community/mods), use a different visual indication, e.g. italics or bold.
- Visually distinguish the related question links. I'd argue that the markup is incorrect here as it's currently a div that contains an`<a><br>` pair for each link. As it represents a list (of links to related questions), it should be an `<ul>` instead. Render it with bullet points and it's clear where a new link starts.

  If `<ul>` is not an option, a budget variant would be increasing the space between the links by adding appropriate CSS for the `<br>` (or even simply adding a second `<br>` in between each link).
- The "Google search" element feels a bit out of place. As OP recommends, it could be made its own `<li>` instead of being a child of the "related questions" list item. I don't think that would be a good solution, because it belongs there semantically: the whole list item is about finding similar SO questions, thus it holds links to related questions, SO search, and a site-specific Google search. Instead of giving it its own `<li>`, we could simply reword the sentence above the related questions to include both search links, e.g. "*Try searching for similar questions with [SO search] or [Google search]*".
- Replacing the title with "Question Removed" or a similar wording would better describe what's actually going on. See [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256134/improve-the-404-not-found-error-page-for-deleted-questions) for a discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, font size needs to be consistent as well as simple formatting refinements.

If you check out the `404` page for Meta (and Stack Overflow, but with a different picture), it's *much* neater:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>
    
    <title>Page Not Found - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91" />
            
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=fb0ca4ff15b3">
    
<style type="text/css">
    .content-page > ul > li, .search-results { margin-bottom:20px; } 
    .search-results { padding-top: 10px; font-size: 80%; }
    .question-hyperlink { font-weight: normal; }
    .leftcol { width:420px; float:left }
    .rightcol { width:510px; float:right; margin-bottom:30px; }
</style>

    
    
    
</head>
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
    <noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <div id="overlay-header"></div>
    <div id="custom-header"></div>




<div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-wrapper">

        <div class="js-topbar-dialog-corral">

<div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno">
    <div class="header">
        <h3><a href="//stackoverflow.com">current community</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content current-site-container">
        <ul class="current-site">
                <li>
                        <div class="related-links">
            <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })"
>chat</a>
                    <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:7 })"
>blog</a>
                    <a href="/users/logout" class="js-gps-track"     data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:8 })"
>log out</a>
    </div>




    <a href="//stackoverflow.com"
    <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
       class="current-site-link site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="552"
       data-gps-track="
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:4 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
        Meta Stack Overflow
    </a>

                </li>
                            <li class="related-site">
                        <div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
        <span class="L-shaped-icon"></span>
    </div>

                    <a class="site-link js-gps-track"
                       href="//careers.stackoverflow.com?utm_source=meta.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=site-ui&utm_campaign=multicollider"
                            data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:9 })"
>
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-careers" title="Stack Overflow Careers"></div>
                        Stack Overflow Careers
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="header" id="your-communities-header">
        <h3>
                <a href="//stackexchange.com/users/2817331/?tab=accounts">your communities</a>
        </h3>
            
            <a href="#" id="edit-pinned-sites">edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="cancel-pinned-sites" style="display: none;">cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content" id="your-communities-section">
            
            <ul class="my-sites">
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//stackoverflow.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="1"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:1, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div>
        Stack Overflow
            <span class="rep-score">1,356</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//superuser.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="3"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:3, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-superuser" title="Super User"></div>
        Super User
            <span class="rep-score">328</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//security.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="162"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:162, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-security" title="Information Security"></div>
        Information Security
            <span class="rep-score">255</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//scifi.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="186"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:186, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-scifi" title="Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy"></div>
        Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy
            <span class="rep-score">213</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        



    <a href="//travel.stackexchange.com"
       class="site-link js-gps-track"
       data-id="273"
       data-gps-track="
            site.switch({ target_site:273, item_type:3 }),
        site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-travel" title="Travel"></div>
        Travel
            <span class="rep-score">192</span>
    </a>

                    </li>
            </ul>
                <div class="pinned-site-editor-container" style="display: none;">
                    <input id="js-site-search-txt"
                           type="text"
                           class="site-filter-input"
                           value=""
                           placeholder="Add a Stack Exchange community"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="pin-site-btn" value="Add" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <ul class="js-found-sites found-sites"></ul>
                    <ul class="pinned-site-list sortable" data-custom-list="False">
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save-pinned-sites-btn" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <a href="#" id="reset-pinned-sites">reset to default list</a>
                </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="header">
        <h3><a href="//stackexchange.com/sites">more stack exchange communities</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="child-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="network-items">

            <a href="//stackexchange.com"
               class="topbar-icon icon-site-switcher yes-hover js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track"
               data-gps-track="site_switcher.show"
               title="A list of all 134 Stack Exchange sites">
                <span class="hidden-text">Stack Exchange</span>
            </a>

                <a href="#"
                   class="topbar-icon icon-inbox yes-hover js-inbox-button"
                   title="Recent inbox messages">
                    <span class="hidden-text">Inbox</span>
                    <span class="unread-count" style="display:none"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#"
                   class="topbar-icon icon-achievements yes-hover js-achievements-button "
                   data-unread-class=""
                   title="Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned">
                    <span class="hidden-text">Reputation and Badges</span>
                    <span class="unread-count" style="display:none">
                        
                    </span>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="topbar-links">

                <a href="/users/2422013/%ca%8e%c7%9d%ca%9euo%c9%af%c9%b9%c7%9dq%ca%8e%c9%94" class="profile-me js-gps-track" data-gps-track="profile_summary.click()">
                    <div class="gravatar-wrapper-24" title="ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNzRu.png?s=24&g=1" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me"></div>
                    <div class="links-container topbar-flair">

                        <span class="reputation" title="your reputation: 1,356">
                            1,356
                        </span>
<span title="14 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">14</span></span><span title="34 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">34</span></span>                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="links-container">
                    <span class="topbar-menu-links">



                            <a href="/review" title="Review queues - help improve the site">
                                review
                            </a>

    <a href="#" class="icon-help js-help-button" title="Help Center and other resources">
        help
        <span class="triangle"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="topbar-dialog help-dialog js-help-dialog dno">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="//stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:5 })">
                            Back to Stack Overflow
                            <span class="item-summary">
                                Return to the main site
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                        <a href="/tour" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:1 })">
                            Tour
                            <span class="item-summary">
                                Start here for a quick overview of the site
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/help" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:4 })">
                        Help Center
                        <span class="item-summary">
                            Detailed answers to any questions you might have
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/help/whats-meta" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:3 })">
                            What&#39;s Meta?
                            <span class="item-summary">
                                How Meta is different from the main site
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

                    </span>
                </div>

            <div class="search-container">
                <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="search" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" />
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        StackExchange.ready(function() { StackExchange.topbar.init(); });
    </script>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <br class="cbt">
            <div id="hlogo">
                <a href="/">
                    Stack Overflow
                        <span class="meta-title">meta</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="hmenus">
                <div class="nav mainnavs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/help/badges">Badges</a></li>
                        <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav askquestion">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="nav-askquestion"  href="/questions/ask">Ask Question</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        



        <div id="content" class="snippet-hidden">
            


<div id="mainbar-full">
    <div class="subheader">
        <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-page leftcol">        
        <p>We&#39;re sorry, we couldn&#39;t find the page you requested.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
Try <a href="/search">searching for similar questions</a>                        </li>
            <li>Browse <a href="/questions">recent questions</a></li>
            <li>Browse <a href="/tags">popular tags</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>If you feel something is missing that should be here, <a href="/contact">contact us</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">    
            <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/keyboard-waffles.jpg" width="500" alt="page not found">
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="categories">
        <div class="footerwrap">
            <div id="footer-menu">
                <div class="top-footer-links">
                    <a href="/help">help</a>
                    <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com?blb=1">blog</a>
                        <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com">chat</a>
                    <a href="http://data.stackexchange.com">data</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal">legal</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy">privacy policy</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/work-here">work here</a>
                    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/mediakit">advertising info</a>

                    <a onclick='StackExchange.switchMobile("on")'>mobile</a>
                    <b><a href="/contact">contact us</a></b>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="footer-sites">
                    <table>
    <tr>
            <th colspan=3>
                Technology
            </th>
            <th >
                Life / Arts
            </th>
            <th >
                Culture / Recreation
            </th>
            <th >
                Science
            </th>
            <th >
                Other
            </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//stackoverflow.com" title="professional and enthusiast programmers">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//serverfault.com" title="system and network administrators">Server Fault</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//superuser.com" title="computer enthusiasts and power users">Super User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//webapps.stackexchange.com" title="power users of web applications">Web Applications</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//askubuntu.com" title="Ubuntu users and developers">Ask Ubuntu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//webmasters.stackexchange.com" title="pro webmasters">Webmasters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gamedev.stackexchange.com" title="professional and independent game developers">Game Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//tex.stackexchange.com" title="users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems">TeX - LaTeX</a></li>
                            </ol></td><td><ol>
                        <li><a href="//programmers.stackexchange.com" title="professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development">Programmers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//unix.stackexchange.com" title="users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.">Unix &amp; Linux</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//apple.stackexchange.com" title="power users of Apple hardware and software">Ask Different (Apple)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//wordpress.stackexchange.com" title="WordPress developers and administrators">WordPress Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gis.stackexchange.com" title="cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals">Geographic Information Systems</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//electronics.stackexchange.com" title="electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts">Electrical Engineering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//android.stackexchange.com" title="enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system">Android Enthusiasts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//security.stackexchange.com" title="Information security professionals">Information Security</a></li>
                            </ol></td><td><ol>
                        <li><a href="//dba.stackexchange.com" title="database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community">Database Administrators</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//drupal.stackexchange.com" title="Drupal developers and administrators">Drupal Answers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//sharepoint.stackexchange.com" title="SharePoint enthusiasts">SharePoint</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//ux.stackexchange.com" title="user experience researchers and experts">User Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//mathematica.stackexchange.com" title="users of Mathematica">Mathematica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//salesforce.stackexchange.com" title="Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between">Salesforce</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology" class="more">
                                more (14)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//photo.stackexchange.com" title="professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers">Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//scifi.stackexchange.com" title="science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts">Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com" title="Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts">Graphic Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//cooking.stackexchange.com" title="professional and amateur chefs">Seasoned Advice (cooking)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//diy.stackexchange.com" title="contractors and serious DIYers">Home Improvement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//money.stackexchange.com" title="people who want to be financially literate">Personal Finance &amp; Money</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//academia.stackexchange.com" title="academics and those enrolled in higher education">Academia</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts" class="more">
                                more (10)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//english.stackexchange.com" title="linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts">English Language &amp; Usage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//skeptics.stackexchange.com" title="scientific skepticism">Skeptics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//judaism.stackexchange.com" title="those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more">Mi Yodeya (Judaism)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//travel.stackexchange.com" title="road warriors and seasoned travelers">Travel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//christianity.stackexchange.com" title="committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more">Christianity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//gaming.stackexchange.com" title="passionate videogamers on all platforms">Arqade (gaming)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//bicycles.stackexchange.com" title="people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles">Bicycles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//rpg.stackexchange.com" title="gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games">Role-playing Games</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation" class="more">
                                more (21)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//math.stackexchange.com" title="people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields">Mathematics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//stats.stackexchange.com" title="people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization">Cross Validated (stats)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//cstheory.stackexchange.com" title="theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields">Theoretical Computer Science</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//physics.stackexchange.com" title="active researchers, academics and students of physics">Physics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//mathoverflow.net" title="professional mathematicians">MathOverflow</a></li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://stackexchange.com/sites#science" class="more">
                                more (7)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li><a href="//stackapps.com" title="apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API">Stack Apps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//meta.stackexchange.com" title="meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&amp;A websites">Meta Stack Exchange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//area51.stackexchange.com" title="proposing new sites in the Stack Exchange network">Area 51</a></li>
                        <li><a href="//careers.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow Careers</a></li>
                    
                </ol>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="copyright">
                site design / logo &#169; 2015 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license">cc by-sa 3.0</a>                   with <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/" rel="license">attribution required</a>
            </div>
            <div id="svnrev">
                rev 2015.1.30.2258
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <noscript>
        <div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
    </noscript>

    <script>
</body>
</html>
```