# How to find some specific font types of SO

Tags: support

I actually don't know is this the right section to ask this question, however I don't know where to ask either.

[This](http://3.1m.yt/ySl2umg.jpg) picture is the Page not found error message of SO

I want to find the font type of this. Could anyone point me how can I determine it?

Comment: If no one answers, try this https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 0):

That question was answered on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71550/what-font-is-used-in-the-so-error-page/71552#71552) by the same WhatTheFont service pointed out by [Pekka 웃](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%ec%9b%83)

> the font is [Pragmata](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fsd/pragmata/tt)

And here is a complete overview of the font:

[image]

(credits to [Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097) and [Matt Alexander](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code#comment6716_252184))

Do note that the font is not public domain, so read the [legal stuff](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fsd/pragmata/licensing.html) if you're planning on using the font in your own app or website.