# 404 Error page says "We found this program" but does not actually contain a program on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, error-message

To replicate this, visit any Stack Overflow URL that does not exist, like https://stackoverflow.com/nonexistent.

Here is what that looks like on iOS 10, Safari:

[image: Screenshot]

It says:

> We did, however, find this program.

The page contains no program though.

Comment: I'm seeing it too on Android+Chrome. Naturally, the non-mobile version of that page *does* have the program.

Comment: But instead of clicking the "contact us" link, you decided to post on Meta?

Comment: Although it may be a bug, I'm interested to know how it affects the general operation of the site. ;-)

Comment: @MrLister: I think you're joking, but FWIW, the "contact us" link says, "If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta." So it's quite possible that (s)he *did* click there, and ended up here.

Comment: After minutes of thinking I realized that [the picture is the program](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes, and it's not visible on Android. The text "this program" isn't even a link.

Comment: It all seems to make sense to me. I think the 'program' it found was Stackoverflow. It rendered a custom 404 page as opposed to some generic 404 response from IIS.

Comment: @Brad Right, the question isn't asking what "program" they're talking about or what the program has to do with the 404 page, it's pointing out that the program doesn't show up on mobile browsers.

Comment: @KyleStrand what "program" is expected if not Stackoverflow? I don't get the issue here. They went to a non-existent URL and got a 404 page. That's what happens isn't it?

Comment: @Brad Actually, looking at [this link which explains the program in question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252187/1858225), it's not a stack overflow at all. That link, as well as ChristianGollhardt's comment above, should clear up your confusion.

Answer (score 30):

This was supposed to be a funny joke that relates to how the 404 page is rendered on desktop, with an arty "program" displayed alongside the error text:

[image]

Since this image is not displayed on mobile, the text is a bug.

Comment: Suggestion: *arty "program" --> obfuscated polyglot. Maybe mention the fact that some of the languages it works for are esolangs. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252187/1394393).

Comment: Not really relevant

Comment: @jpmc26 Agree that's not relevant to the question here, but appreciate the link. Thanks.