# Meta shows the Stack Overflow Jobs 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, 404-not-found

Stack Overflow Jobs has a different 404 page: When entering a non-existing URL starting with `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/` (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/gimme-404/)), instead of the usual [404 polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code/252187#252187), a different, SO-Jobs-related 404 page is shown (without a proper HTML `<title>` by the way, but that is a different story).

This is also the case on meta: When entering any URL starting with `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/jobs/` (including this URL), you will see the Jobs 404 page.

On this page, there are several links to help find an existing page. All these links don't work on Meta, which means clicking on one will bring you to the same 404 page again, which will recommend you to go where you just went and unsuccessfully returned.

I know this is a really minor bug, but nevertheless it would be nice if it could be fixed.

Comment: BTW, it seems to be the case in every StackExchange site: http://space.stackexchange.com/jobs/ (not only in meta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the codebase such that the Jobs 404 would only be returned on Jobs routes on sites that have Jobs enabled.