# The 404 page refers to a now-nonexistent program

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found

The 404 program, in all its glory, is gone...

The text, however, still refers to "this program", out of nothingville.

[image: bug]

You can still see the original 404 program, as well as an explanation here: [What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252184/5958455)

Comment: Why was this page changed in the first place?

Comment: @gparyani they couldn't find the old one.

Comment: Perhaps it's a whitespace program? :P

Comment: Hm, would https://stackoverflow.com/PageNotFound be a paradox?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Comment: Looks like the text is now updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text has been updated now, it seems.

The offending line has been changed from

> We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.

to

> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

The rest of the text remains unchanged.

[image: Screenshot of updated text on 404 page]