# Why was the 404 page changed to not include the "program"?

Tags: discussion, support, design, 404-not-found

We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find...wait, what happened to it? It was just here a second ago.

The Stack Overflow 404 error page no longer contains that [polyglot program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/). Why was this changed?

[image: new 404 page]

By the way, the circle in that screenshot demonstrates a [separate, now-fixed bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363133).

**Related:** [Bring back the 404 polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363224/bring-back-the-404-polyglot)

Comment: Is the new image in some way supposed to be related to "page not found"?

Comment: the new image shows a flying object stealing servers

Comment: Ah I see. So the page was abducted by aliens.

Comment: Error 404: the 404 page can't be found

Comment: So you feel something is missing that should be there?

Comment: Suggested image replacement: https://i.imgur.com/nOIyCWV.png

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, a program should be there.

Comment: It looks like the design is changing because of Channels: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/08/information-architecture-navigating-stack-overflow-enterprise-stack-exchange-sites/?cb=1

Comment: The question is what do to with all the post which link to the 404 page to show the polyglot.

Comment: Bring back the polyglot, it has *historical significance*!

Comment: Related: [Can I tattoo the Stack Overflow 404 polyglot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194734/7586)

Answer (score -114, accepted):

We updated several pages ([404](https://stackoverflow.com/404), [error](https://stackoverflow.com/error), [captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha)) so that they worked better across all instances of Stack Overflow (public, channels, enterprise). In the past we have allowed experiences to fork across the various permutations of Q&A. That has a nasty side effect of being hard to manage. We are working to unify our code base so that our experiences are consistent and to simplify maintenance. In the process we made the decision to lose this little piece of Stack Overflow history. Hopefully we've made up for it by giving you space ships and robots.

Comment: +1 for being an explanation of why its gone. -1 for it being gone. ;)

Comment: @Draco18s How about a +1 for the space ships and robots that would get me into the positive.

Comment: Broken links became even more broken, now. What's to happen of all the links to the 404 page which intended to link to the program?

Comment: We don't like robots or alien spaceships, we love waffles and programs!

Comment: oooh they are svg....

Comment: Can't you just implement the polyglot on all those versions?

Comment: Oh, and if you need a new polyglot, [this one works in 178 languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155411/47990). None of them print `404` though.

Comment: @Joe Friend: With all due respect, I hope you're just being facetious in your response to Draco18s, because it's coming off as rather ignorant of the cultural significance behind that little image and how much it means to the community. Granted you acknowledge in your answer that the decision wasn't made lightly, but asking for an upvote to get you into the positive is... likely going to rub people the wrong way.

Comment: I accepted this answer since it properly explains why the 404 polyglot was removed, but have also downvoted it as I want it back.

Comment: I hope Joe's reputation isn't harmed simply because he's the bearer of the bad news. That said, I've downvoted for the same reason as everyone else.

Comment: nah we're fine with joe we just want our polygot back lol

Comment: @DavidB Don't worry, downvotes on Meta don't make anyone lose reputation.

Comment: The amount of down votes that this has received speaks for itself. No comment needed..

Comment: @JakeSymons only 98. Maybe, just maybe, at 1000 Joe will reconsider this change.

Comment: @DonaldDuck no reputation loss, but it sends a clear message. Usually it's useless, but sometimes it helps. :)

Answer (score 92):

Put it back. Please? Before SO loses its soul?

Surely, there's a simple way to have it *default* to something like what's there now and then have a simple to manage config option to enable some flavor text (in Markdown, maybe) and a different image.