# Bring back the 404 polyglot

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, design, 404-not-found

A couple days ago, the Stack Overflow 404 page was changed to no longer contain the [polyglot program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/) that had been present since at least 2009. The given reason, according to [Why was the 404 page changed to not include the "program"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363148/why-was-the-404-page-changed-to-not-include-the-program), was to simplify and unify the codebase across the different implementations of Stack Overflow.

However, I strongly believe that the polyglot should be restored, because it's an important piece of Stack Overflow history. It's also resulted in a lot of broken links becoming even more broken, as people often linked to the 404 page to link to the polyglot. A lot of users have expressed disappointment for this change on the other question.

If the given reason is that it was removed to unify the codebase, why not just implement it on *all* the different implementations (this site, Channels, and Enterprise), instead of specifically singling this site out as was done before? That reason allows implementing it on all or none of it, so just implement it on all of them.

**Update:** Anyone who is interested in bringing it back can change their user icon to https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2NFN.jpg. Credit goes to the4kman in the answers.

Comment: I never really liked the polyglot that much, but I know many did, and at least it had character. A UFO has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. Maybe a sad unicorn? A cabal of high-rep users deleting questions?

Comment: Hey...the first rule of the cabal is....

Comment: @Kobi thing is, Stack Overflow has grown up. Unicorns are for children... UFOs and Robots are for grown ups.

Comment: @Kobi Deleting bad questions should always be encouraged!

Comment: @Skipper New users often think this is just like other forums, where other users and mods establish the rules, and get mad when we aggressively enforce them. Little do they know that the rules are actually part of the site, and integral to the site's operation.

Comment: [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170301025414/stackoverflow.com/404) is a web archive the old 404 page while we're waiting to get it back.

Comment: "it's an important piece of Stack Overflow history" - Why was it important? RE: "why not just implement it on all the different implementations" - I would have thought that was obvious - why would parenting stack exchange or Buddhism stack exchange want a 404 page with a load of cryptic (to non programmers) code?

Comment: Though I am taking "unify our code base" and "various permutations of Q&A" in Joe's linked answer to be talking about across SE not just SO.

Comment: @Kobi: perhaps (cue "Jaws" theme)....Jon Skeet?!?

Comment: @gparyani as a new user, agreed. It would be great to find a way to make this more apparent to new users.

Comment: @JessB thing is that we already tell everyone that, when they first ask a question, what the rules are, and that has been like that since 2011.

Comment: @Braiam I get that. I didn't mean the rules themselves, I meant that distinction: that clean content generation is the goal of the site and the rules are integral to that, unlike other forum sites where the goals might be different (as described by gparyani). That's an important distinction, and it seems it is being missed by a lot of new users (myself included, until someone directly explained it to me). It might be nice to find a way make that concept more apparent to new users in addition to the rules themselves.

Comment: @Braiam To add to Jess's comment, on most forums, mods tend to be more lenient with the rules to newer users, whereas here, we hold each question to the same quality guidelines (for good reason). New users have a hard time understanding that.

Comment: @MartinSmith The different implementations are the ones I was referring to in Joe Friend's answer to the other question: this site, Channels, and Enterprise.

Comment: And that's a problem with the users, the fist time I asked a question on SO I read the rules of SO, when I post on a forum, I read the rules of said forum. Following the rules of the host when you are a guest is basic, it shouldn't need to be said @JessB.

Comment: @JessB all of that is in the tour.

Comment: @TinyGiant Which not many people read, or some people just scroll all the way down just to earn the badge.

Comment: Funny coincidence, [I authored the polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252187/126042) some eight and half years ago, and I've been absent from Stack Exchange for a few years, just logged in again for no particular reason... sad to see it's not used any more. I have nostalgic memories of a couple late, late nights hacking on that 404 polyglot.

Comment: @MarkRushakoff What a coincidence! The polyglot was just removed a couple days before I posted this. Incidentally, I browsed a day before the [first post on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363133/the-404-page-refers-to-a-now-nonexistent-program?noredirect=1&lq=1), and hit the polyglot 404 page.

Comment: I've never seen 404 on SO. So I'm surprised about Polyglot :)

Comment: At the very least display an error such as 404 when the Polyglot can't be found!

Comment: Just my opinion: I'm here for almost 6 years, yet never understood a syllable of what apparantly is known as the polyglot, even though I am a programming veteran of 20+ years. I found - and still find - it way too confusing for the average user. I say good riddance, and no need to get all sentimental about an inside joke that I think just a small percentage of users will get and that will just confuse everyone else.

Comment: I have no idea why people are so desperate to get this back. Yeah it was fun, but it's an 8 year old joke now...

Comment: @DavidG A good joke ages well, as this one (along with a keyboard shaped waffle) did.

Comment: So similar vintage to the "6-8 weeks" and "red freehand circles"  jokes which also are well past their use by date IMO

Comment: Have you tried contacting support as it says on the 404 page? ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 A joke can age well and still be boring. This one has past it's sell-by date now imo. Also, how many people actually understand what it is? I'd say a tiny handful of dedicated SO users get it.

Comment: If it's to "simplify and unify the codebase", then why is the [Meta 404 Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404) still the keyboard waffle? Also, all other network sites seem to have custom 404 images, so I'm not sure what this has to do with the codebase...

Comment: @Toastrackenigma When I said that, I meant the main SO public site, Channels, and Enterprise. But you should ask this as a comment on Joe Friend's answer to my other question.

Comment: @gparyani Yeah, his explanation makes no sense. They have a 404 template page used on all network sites, with different images for each site with a theme. They could just have easily used the old polygot image rather than the new UFO - it has nothing to do with the codebase

Comment: @Toastrackenigma the polyglot page had different text on the RHS too - not just a different image

Comment: @PeterB more or less confusing than a panda on a rocking horse? (which is what you see if you go to notexist.stackexchange.com, for example...). Its fairly obvious its a coding joke, and a quick google search explains it. I don't see how its possibly confusing, given that its just an image after an ordinary 404 page.

Comment: @DavidG Oh, good Lord. Don't be ridiculous. Just because its old doesn't mean it's not fun. Little touches like that help keep us from taking ourselves too seriously and lighten the mood of the site. And people call me a stick in the mud.

Comment: @jpmc26 And an alien ship stealing stuff is also fun, probably for a lot more people than the ployglot image. You need to chill out a little buddy*! I couldn't give two hoots what the 404 page is, I'll just never understand why people get so attached to stuff and resistant to change.  *Don't take that comment too seriously, I'm just jesting :)

Comment: @DavidG An alien ship has nothing to do with the site's subject matter. As such, it lacks any cleverness or relevance. It's clearly a downgrade. That's why it's not any fun. =p

Comment: @jpmc26 I spend a lot of time in skeptics groups, there's a lot of people that believe aliens have everything to do with everything!

Comment: @the4kman What's the difference between the old one and new one?

Comment: @gparyani I edited the original post as well, quoted: "the "a" had a discoloration in the second line, it annoyed me WAY too much"

Comment: This should now be possible. Travel has their own 404 image: https://travel.stackexchange.com/brokenurl - and so does Meta.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/brokenurl

Answer (score -44, accepted):

I understand and am empathetic towards the up voters desire to maintain this 404 page as is for historic reasons. However, for the reasons stated in my [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363193/7782017) we won't be reinstating it.

Comment: The given reason in that answer is so 404 pages can be the same on public, Channels, and enterprise. Why not use the same polyglot on all of them?

Comment: @gparyani Ultimately we will be unifying these pages across the network. The polyglot doesn't work for non-developers who are a large percentage of our users on network sites as well as Teams and Enterprise. Even all developers don't get the polyglot page. It's had it's run, but the joke done played out.

Answer (score 114):

As an avid supporter of the polyglot, I changed my profile picture to this:

[image]

Join me if you want.

Comment: So I assume your code is also a polyglot? if so, please add an explanation of the languages used etc...

Comment: @Tschallacka Of course, my bad. It uses 326 different languages and throws a compiler error in each one of them.

Comment: Just joined in as well.

Comment: World War IV: Fight for the Polygot.

Comment: That "↵" means `#the` should be a continuation of the second line, not the third line :P

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It also means "return", which is a synonym of "back". Symbolism is my drug.

Comment: Yeah I understood why you put it here, I just wanted to annoy you :P

Comment: I used that image in my profile picture in a creative way. You can look at my profile to see what I did.

Comment: Is it too soon for this to become a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306913/364194)?

Comment: @DonaldDuck You really like Donald Duck, huh?

Comment: If you can convince Jon Skeet (and others with mega high rep) to change avatar to this, we have real chance of SE changing their mind. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You have plenty of space on the right side of your profile pic and you already have more rep than me. If you know what I mean ;)

Comment: @the4kman oh I know... but without support of the really big guns, it would be pointless to change. ;)

Comment: Used that image. Now i only have to post something really stupid under the c# tag. Jon Skeet is gonna correct me and we can convince him to change his pic

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you could hack into Jeff Atwood's account and change... you'll soon be bludgeoned to death with a giant polyglot.

Comment: @iBug I pinged him in chat, should be enough on my part. Oh wait, you said Jeff, thought you meant Jon Skeet. Jeff has no power anymore, so changing his avatar won't make much difference... ;)

Comment: @TobiasTheel combine C# and Java somehow, think Skeet would love it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Jeff has no power anymore, but why does the God of Memes need power?

Comment: @ShadowWizard so a question that includes a JNI Wrapper in C# love the idea ^^

Comment: @TobiasTheel yeah that might work. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you can also ping him at this meta discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363508/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-podcasts?cb=1

Comment: This would be cooler if it was a polyglot in itself